# How can i retrieve HumanApi publicToken by passing clientUserId instead humanId?

Tags: health-monitoring, fitbit

I understand that i can retrieve publicToken by supplying following data

{
humanId: "",
clientId: "",
sessionToken: ""
}

Source: https://hub.humanapi.co/docs/finalizing-user-authentication#section-retrieve-the-publictoken-for-an-existing-user

[image]

But I don't have humanId, However i could pass clientUserId. Is there any humanApi url/method that i could use to achieve this ?